# MacBook Air Will Not Restart

Tags: macbook-pro, crash

Yesterday, my 2013 MacBook Air powered down unexpectedly, and since then I have not been able to restart it. It appears to be cycling through restart and shutdown every 5 seconds. I can feel that the case is heating up and the fans turn on but then they shut off and the cycle restarts. The screen remains blank, and there are no start up bells.

I have tried the various shortcuts I have found on Google to restart my Mac, but none have worked. What should I do next?

Answer (score 1):

It was a problem on the motherboard. I had to take it to apple and they changed it.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like **PRAM** corruption.

Locate the following keys on the keyboard: Command (⌘), Option, P, and R. Press and hold the Command-Option-P-R keys immediately after you hear the startup sound. Hold these keys until the computer restarts and you hear the startup sound for a second time

Comment: He said he doesn't hear a startup sound.

Comment: I dont hear any sound at all and I already tried that keyboard combination :(

Comment: I suggested it because I had a similar problem with my Macbook pro and it worked for me. Try installing OS X on an external disk and booting up from it.